# Swift- Fetching realm object based on primary key

Tags: ios, swift, realm, primary-key

I am using Realm for storing data offline. I need to fetch the row according to the primary key but I am getting nil as the response.
Here is my Model class

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class DCContactListModel: Object {

    @objc dynamic var mProfile_pic:String?
    @objc dynamic var mSalutation:String?
    @objc dynamic var mStatus:String?
    @objc dynamic var mTitle:String?
    @objc dynamic var mUid:String?

    //property

     var mUserIndex: Int?
     var mIsSelected = false


    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "mUid"
    }

    func initWithUserChatDictionary(userDictionary:Dictionary<String, Any>) -> DCContactListModel{

        if let profile_pic = userDictionary["profile_pic"] {
            mProfile_pic = profile_pic as? String
        }
        if let salutation = userDictionary["salutation"] {
            mSalutation = salutation as? String
        }
        if let status = userDictionary["status"] {
            mStatus = status as? String
        }
        if let title = userDictionary["title"] {
            mTitle = title as? String
        }
        if let uid = userDictionary["uid"] {
            mUid = uid as? String
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

here i add code to access data using object

```
let primaryKey = "8687tuyguyhytu6ruf76fyt7"
 let realm = try! Realm()
 let specificPerson = realm.object(ofType: DCContactListModel.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey)
        print(specificPerson!)
```

but getting specific person as nil but when I checked in table this primary key is there. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You must override default init method. Why dont you store entire dictionary instead of creating multiple property. Here check my code done with **Data**  class. You missing init method and that might be the problem.

```
convenience init(userDictionary:Dictionary<String, Any>) {
 self.init()
    if let profile_pic = userDictionary["profile_pic"] {
            mProfile_pic = profile_pic as? String
        }
        if let salutation = userDictionary["salutation"] {
            mSalutation = salutation as? String
        }
        if let status = userDictionary["status"] {
            mStatus = status as? String
        }
        if let title = userDictionary["title"] {
            mTitle = title as? String
        }
        if let uid = userDictionary["uid"] {
            mUid = uid as? String
        }
}
```

**Sample.swift**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Sample: Object {

// Specify properties to ignore (Realm won't persist these)

//  override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
//    return []
//  }
    private(set) dynamic var sectionName = ""
    private(set) dynamic var data = Data()

    /**
     Override Object.primaryKey() to set the model’s primary key. Declaring a primary key allows objects to be looked up and updated efficiently and enforces uniqueness for each value.
     */
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "sectionName"
    }

    convenience init(sectionName: String, data: Data) {
        self.init()
        self.sectionName = sectionName
        self.data = data
    }
}





//MARK: DATABASE CODE
    func saveData(data:Data, sectionName:String) -> Void {
        let obj = Sample(sectionName: sectionName, data: data)
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write({
            // If update = true, objects that are already in the Realm will be
            // updated instead of added a new.
            realm.add(obj, update: true)
        })
    }
    func deleteData(sectionName:String){
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let data = realm.object(ofType: Sample.self, forPrimaryKey: sectionName)
        if data != nil{
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(data!)
            }
        }
    }
    func getData(sectionName:String,completion: @escaping (_ Data: Data, _ isContain:Bool) -> Void){
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let data = realm.object(ofType: Sample.self, forPrimaryKey: sectionName)
        if data != nil{
            completion((data?.data)!, true)
        }else{
            completion(Data(), false)
        }

    }
```

**Sample Usage**

```
self.deleteData(sectionName:"primary key")
        self.saveData(data: result, sectionName:"primary key")

self.getData(sectionName: "primary key") { (data, isAvailable) in
            if isAvailable {
}
}
```

Comment: I followed same steps you mentioned still isAvailable is false.

Comment: Did you call save function?

Comment: yes I called. When I am checking the realm table that primary key is present.

Comment: Can you pls update the modified code and where u calling save function with values? Make sure storing dictionary not empty